# What would this remote desktop client computers weakest link be?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

System: lga 1156 socket/h55chipset, i5 680 processor(integrated graphics), 4gb 1333 ram, 1gb/s lan/router with 4mb/s down .5 up internet

I have built a PC that will have about 3 people remoting into it. It seems quite a bit more sluggish when more than 1 person is logged in, so I was just wondering what you think the weakest link would be in the system for remote desktop use? I was thinking it was the internet connection but when I tested it from within the network it didn't seem any faster really so just wondering??
thx

- I'm just using windows built in RDP through win 8 pro. It's all working it just gets really sluggish with multiple users. So was wondering which part of my setup RDP most relies on that could be causing it to be sluggish?
  thx
- I changed the termsrv.dll file and changed a couple things in regedit. I Had to go this route since microsoft randomly doesn't allow multiple rdp sessions in server 2012 when setup as a "workgroup" like ours is. But anyways, I didn't think it was the isp's speeds since it was sluggish even within the network but now it's randomly working fine. So maybe we just had lots of traffic going through the router earlier. It's all still in testing stages but I'll probably still look into upping our upload speeds.
  thx for the comments they helped stir my brain.

Comment: What are you using with Remote Desktop? Is it RDP, VNC, or other? What is the Host OS? What is the expected outcome? What have you troubleshooted already?

Comment: Your upload speeds are terrible... I would start here...

Comment: Your bottlekneck is your upstream.  Its simply not powerful enough to support 3 users.

Comment: hey thx. I will look into our isp to see what I can do and start with that. Now on a side note... I'm new here is there a way to mark this as answered or not how this site works?

Comment: What are these three users doing when it's sluggish?  What do the resources for the OS look like while it's acting sluggish?  What method did you use to hack Windows 8 into allowing more than one RDP connection in (how you did it may matter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weakest link is your Upload speed and average response time (in ms) (because you are using ADSL router).

If possible change your internet provider and bottleneck will gone.

Comment: The author does not indicate they are using an ADSL router.